# npm ERR! SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:365

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, npm-install

I am facing these error which installing  the angular-cl globally.

Below is the error :

> npm ERR! request to
>   registry.npmjs.org/supports-color/-/supports-color-2.0.0.tgz failed,
>   reason: 0:error:1408F10B:SSL ro utines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version
>   number:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:365

Is it related to configuration of NPM  proxy ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Any help is much appreciated. Thanx